# Running External Programs in Julia with special characters ">"

Tags: julia, special-characters, external

I want run an external program in Julia which contains the special characters ">"

```
gunzip -c file.nc.gz > file.nc
```

But I get this error:

```
ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: parsing command `gunzip -c $filein /> $fileout`:
       special characters "#{}()[]<>|&*?~;" must be quoted in commands
```

I can I solve this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Use [`pipeline`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.pipeline-Tuple%7BBase.AbstractCmd%7D) instead of using shell syntax (`>`) for stream redirection.

Example:

```
shell> ls
file.txt.gz

julia> p = pipeline(`gunzip -c file.txt.gz`; stdout="file.txt");

julia> run(p);

shell> ls
file.txt  file.txt.gz

shell> cat file.txt
hello, world
```

Alternatively you can invoke a shell that understand what `>` means, for example `bash`:

```
run(`/bin/bash -c "gunzip -c file.txt.gz > file.txt"`)
```